# Euclidean distance between elements in two different matrices?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to determine the Euclidean distance for my documents from their centroids. The dimensions of the two arrays in question (`points` and `centers`) satisfy the `XA` and `XB` dimensional requirements for `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`, but I don't know why I'm getting the below `ValueError`.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

corpus = pd.Series(["bye bye brutal good bye apple banana orange", "bye bye hello apple banana", "corn wheat apple banana goodbye cookie brutal", "fruit cake banana apple bye sweet sweet"])
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
model = Kmeans(n_clusters = 2)
model.fit(X)
centers = model.cluster_centroids_

cdist(X, centers)
```

This is the error I get:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

From `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`'s documentation:

```
Parameters: XA: ndarray
    An Ma by n array of Ma original observations in an n-dimensional space
            XB: ndarray
    An Mb by n array of Mb original observations in an n-dimensional space
...
```

My `X` and `centers` `numpy` arrays certainly satisfy these dimensional conditions for `cdist`, right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small change that you need to do:

```
cdist(X.toarray(),centers)
```

Since X is an object of type `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` it will not be directly taken as a valid input by the scipy function. The method toarray() converts it to a valid numpy array